# How to draw a line in a chart?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to enter number in TextBox and draw a line in a chart depending on entered value. Please view my image below.A chart is located on a form. Does anybody know how to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an UI-element line. This line has a property called something like "Left". It tells you how far to the left it is located relative to the left side of the application window. You can change this property with VBA code on runtime.

You take the textbox and put something like this code in the AfterUpdate-event of the textbox:

> ```
> Private Sub textBox_AfterUpdate()
>     Me.Line.Left = me.Textbox.Value * someValue
> End Sub
> ```

Alternative you can use the Change-Event. Whatever works better.

The exact Value for the variable someValue you would have to find out for yourself. It depends on the width of the display. Keep in mind there are different resolutions and display widths.